# Neo4j find repeating pattern starting from node

Tags: design-patterns, neo4j, cypher, relation, repeat

I'm currently working with Neo4j and trying to construct a Cypher query which suits my use case. I have a graph with the following structure.

`(NODE_A)-RELATION_A->(NODE_B)-RELATION_B->(NODE_A)-RELATION_A->` ... *repeat* ...

I know the first **NODE_A** and want each subsequent **NODE_A** and **NODE_B** which match the two Relations (RELATION_A and RELATION_B). If I construct a cipher query it looks like this.

`MATCH (a:NODE_A)-[:RELATION_A]->(b:NODE_B)-[:RELATION_B]-(c:NODE_A) WHERE id(a)=1 RETURN [a,b,c] as result`

But this only returns as result the pattern: `NODE_A-RELATION_A->NODE_B-RELATION_B->NODE_A`

If I leave out the `WHERE id(a) = 1` it get the correct result, but then it returns all nodes that match the pattern.

How do I specify a start node from which the query will execute from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to look to APOC Procedures here, as there currently isn't a way to define a repeating sequence of node labels or relationship types in just Cypher.

We actually just added [such a feature](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_sequences) to APOC's [path expander procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths).

Using your case, usage would look like:

```
MATCH (a:NODE_A)
WHERE id(a) = 1
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(a, {sequence:'NODE_A, RELATION_A>, NODE_B, RELATION_B>'}) YIELD path
RETURN collect(last(nodes(path))) as results
```

This will expand out from your starting node, repeating the sequence of both node labels and relationships.

Comment: Using APOC procedures is correct here. You can do a traversal of the tree with expandConfig. Also apoc.path.spanningTree works with a labelFilter.  So this is suitable for my use case. Thanky you :-)